# How to scroll in a ListView

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, scroll, flutter-layout

My screen have one widget from top to middle screen, and the follow widget stands from middle to bottom. I only want scroll the second (the following) widget:

```dart
 Widget _showList(){
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: _sEv.length !=null
          ? ListView.builder(
        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: _sEv.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              _showTimePicker(context, index);
            },
            child: Dismissible(
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10), child: Icon(Icons.calendar_today_rounded)),
                title: Text(mytxt),
                subtitle: Text(mytxt2)
              key: UniqueKey(),
              direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
              onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) {
                setState(() {
                  //do something
                });
            }
          ),);
        },
      )
          : Center(child: Text("there is nothing here")),
    );
  }
```

But it is not scrolling at all, what I'm missing? This widget is being called from a column widget ( the first one on screen )

*Update (where showList is called)*

```dart
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            TableCalendar(
              //default code in flutter doc
            ),
            Divider(),

            _showList(),
          ],
```

Comment: So, can you clarify it in a answer?

Comment: You used three scroll view inside together, which one you want to be scrollable

Comment: I wrote two SCSV, but I want the first to be scrolled. (the first code _showList)

Comment: If you only need to scrool the bottom listview then remove your ```SingleChildScrollView```

Comment: I removed and : `Column's children must not contain any null values, but a null value was found at index 2`

Comment: There is notheing inside your  ```TableCalendar()``` now thats the problem.

Comment: for testing your target output remove your ```TableCalendar()``` and put this line

```Container(child:Text('Hello I am on the top'),),```

Comment: I removed the first SCSV. Now I remove the SCSV from tableCalendar and it overflows the screen

Comment: My table calendar is normal

Comment: just return the listview from your `_showList()` method and remove those 3 line from your listview

```physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),``` ```scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,``` ```shrinkWrap: true,```

Comment: `Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.`

Comment: I got it by removing Single Child Scroll view from both places and wrapping a Expanded in the _showList call